# List<List<Char>> + List<Char> = List<Any>?

Tags: kotlin

I have a below code which works.

```
class ListManipulate(val list: List<Char>, val blockCount: Int) {

    val result: MutableList<List<Char>> = mutableListOf()

    fun permute(sequence: List<Int> = emptyList(), start: Int = 0, count: Int = blockCount) {
        if (count == 0) {
            result.add(constructSequence(sequence))
            return
        }
        for (i in start .. list.size - count) {
            permute(sequence + i, i + 1, count - 1)
        }
    }

    private fun constructSequence(sequence: List<Int>): List<Char> {
        var result = emptyList<Char>()
        for (i in sequence) {
            result += list[i]
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

However, when I change the `result` from MutableList to normal List, i.e.

```
    var result: List<List<Char>> = emptyList()
    // ...
            result += constructSequence(sequence)
```

I got this error `Type mismatch. Require: List<List<Char>>; Found: List<Any>`

The full code as below

```
class ListManipulate(val list: List<Char>, val blockCount: Int) {

    var result: List<List<Char>> = emptyList()

    fun permute(sequence: List<Int> = emptyList(), start: Int = 0, count: Int = blockCount) {
        if (count == 0) {
            result += constructSequence(sequence)
            return
        }
        for (i in start .. list.size - count) {
            permute(sequence + i, i + 1, count - 1)
        }
    }

    private fun constructSequence(sequence: List<Int>): List<Char> {
        var result = emptyList<Char>()
        for (i in sequence) {
            result += list[i]
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Why `result + constructSequence(sequence)` would result in `List<Any>` instead of `List<List<Char>>`?

Is there a way I could still use the normal List> and not the mutable list?

Answer (score 2):

CTRL + click on the `+` in IDEA, you'll see that it takes you to the following function:

```
/**
 * Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection and then all elements of the given [elements] collection.
 */
public operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(elements: Iterable<T>): List<T> {
    /* ... */
}
```

Which means that you add all the individual elements of `elements` to the receiver. That is, you'll add all `T`'s to the `List<List<T>>`. Since `List<T>` is not `T`, you'll get `List<Any>` as a result.

Comment: Thanks! Any possible workaround so that I could still have a normal List (instead of MutableList)?

Comment: @Elye give him correct answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @Moira, `addAll` is not usable here, as it is not a mutableList

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `+=` is [overloaded](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/index.html). If it sees an `Iterable`, `Array` or `Sequence` it behaves differently. You have to explicitly use `plusElement()` to achieve the behaviour you intend.

Consider the following code.:

```
class ListManipulate(val list: List<Char>, val blockCount: Int) {

    var result: List<List<Char>> = emptyList()

    fun permute(sequence: List<Int> = emptyList(), start: Int = 0, count: Int = blockCount) {
        if (count == 0) {
            result = result.plusElement(constructSequence(sequence))
            return
        }
        for (i in start..list.size - count) {
            permute(sequence + i, i + 1, count - 1)
        }
    }

    private fun constructSequence(sequence: List<Int>): List<Char> =
        List(sequence.size, { i -> list[sequence[i]] })
}
```

PS: I also took the liberty to update your `constructSequence()` to something more concise.

Btw: `+=` uses `addAll` internally.

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection and then all elements of the given [elements] collection.
>  */
> public operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(elements: Iterable<T>): List<T> {
>     if (elements is Collection) {
>         val result = ArrayList<T>(this.size + elements.size)
>         result.addAll(this)
>         result.addAll(elements)
>         return result
>     } else {
>         val result = ArrayList<T>(this)
>         result.addAll(elements)
>         return result
>     }
> }
> ```

Side note: you can also do:

```
 result.toMutableList().add(constructSequence(sequence))
```

It is fine to return a `MutableList`, the only difference really is that the `List` interface doesnt have the manipulation methods. Internally both are represented by an `ArrayList`

> ```
> @SinceKotlin("1.1")
> @kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
> public inline fun <T> List(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): List<T> = MutableList(size, init)
> ```

Comment: `+=` doesn't always expect both object is the same type. e.g. the `result += list[i]` in the code, is on the LHS is `List<Char>`, while RHS is `Char`

Comment: `+` is overloaded. If the RHS is an `Iterable`, `Array` or `Sequence` it behaves differently than if is something else. Check check https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/index.html -> use `plusElement()`

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer. the `result.plusElement(constructSequence(sequence))` doesn't works. But the previous answer `permutatedList += listOf(constructSequence(sequence))` works.

Comment: I guess it should be `result = result.plusElement(..)` in any case it is creating a new List() every time. You should consider using a `MutableList` internally, if you run into performance problems (i.e. with large `blockCount`)